# How to specify cascade on update on a foreign key using entity framework 6 (code first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with an EF6, code first model and am looking to add Foreign Keys that cascade both on delete and update.

Currently i have definitions like: .ForeignKey("dbo.xxx", t => t.xxx, cascadeDelete: true). An cascadeUpdate configuration option does obviously not exist. How can i specify an cascade on update?

Comment: Something like this? `oFKey.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade;` from [Constraints and Cascading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188919.aspx).

Comment: I don't think EF supports cascadeing updates because don't think it doesn't supports updating properties marked as the primary key.

Comment: Just to clarify/make sure; im not interested in fixing this at the EF level, I just want to use the CreateDatabase call in an Migration to set up a cascading update at the database level